# How much swap space should I configure?

Tags: games, ram, swap, steam, memory-usage

How much swap space should I have? I have a 500GB HDD and 6GB RAM.

My specs:

- Release 12.04 (precise) 64-bit
- Kernel Linux 3.8.0-34-generic
- GNOME 3.4.2
- Memory: 5.7 GiB
- Processor: Intel® Core™ i3-3227U CPU @ 1.90GHz × 4

I just want to run Steam games smoothly.

Comment: that's a nice link from Quasim... nowadays 1xRAM swap would just do fine; depends on the memory usage requirements of the applications you use...

Answer (score 1):

I always set up my swap to be as large as my RAM. This is required for hibernation, but I don't use it.

So, in your case you should have a swap partition that is 6GB.

Comment: Thank you very much! :D Just trying to be on the safe side.